# How to protect a new wood floor from renovation traffic

Tags: flooring, protection

I have had hardwood flooring installed in my home, with further renovation (kitchen) upcoming. The kitchen floor is tile which I'm not worried about, but to get to and from the kitchen means travelling over the hardwood (urethane finish). The installers used cardboard from the shipping boxes to protect the floor as they were working over it. To keep the cardboard from sliding around, it was taped down with painter's tape. It only took them a few days to complete the work, after which I had no trouble removing the tape. The kitchen work is another matter; there will be activity spread over a few weeks.

I'm thinking of using the same technique as the flooring installers - lay down cardboard and secure with painter's tape, but I've read that you can only rely on 7-14 day release. Is this true? Will I have problems removing the tape from the flooring if left in place for 3-4 weeks? Will it damage, discolor or cloud the finish if left that long?

Answer (score 0):

1/8" (or 1/4" if it's cheaper) hardboard (Masonite is a brand name you might or might not know better than the generic term) which can be laid in place and taped together at the seams without taping to the floor.

Comment: There is a  heavy grade  Rosen paper made for specifically for this purpose.  It comes in rolls and is in the painting supplies section of your big box store.  As mentioned taping at the seams.

Comment: Ram board is one brand.

Comment: Does not protect the floor from impacts or sharp things nearly as well as hardboard does.